# Printing an array from method in main

Tags: java, arrays, printing, return

i have an array returned from method, its like `{2,2,3,5,0,0,0,0}` and i want to print it to output from main like: `2*2*3*5`, how can I do this ? Here's my code:

```
RozkladLiczby a=new RozkladLiczby(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.czynnikiPierwsze(Integer.parseInt(args[i]))));
```

When i use `Arrays.toString()` I get output like `{2,2,3,5,0,0,0,0}`.

How can I get it like I wrote before?
`RozkladLiczby` is creatig a array of ints and `czynnikiPierwsze` method is returning an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for printing w/o 0 digits.

```
public class Main {

    static int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0};

    public static void main(String args[]){

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if(a[i]!=0)
                System.out.print(a[i]+"*");    

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your array to print it in the way you want. Have a look into the `Arrays.toString()` method source code to get an idea on how to do that.

It should look like something:

```
int[] arr = a.czynnikiPierwsze(Integer.parseInt(args[i])))
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
          System.out.println("*");
      }
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: I know, but how can i do this ? Should i create a new array in main and = to this an array returned from method ? I mean how can change the array returned from a.czynnikiPierwsze to sth like tab[i]; ?

Comment: not sure to understand your question, please try to update it with clarification and see if my updated answer helps

Answer (score 0):

You could just do :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PrintArray{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String g = Arrays.toString(a.czynnikiPierwsze(Integer.parseInt(args[i])));
    g = g.replace(", 0","");
    g = g.replace(", ","*");
    g = g.replace("[","");
    g = g.replace("]","");
    System.out.println(g);
 }
```

}

INPUT : {2,2,3,5,0,0,0,0}

OUTPUT : 2*2*3*5

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   String s = "";
    for (int n : myArray){
     s += n + "*";
    }
```

Being `myArray` the array of `int` you have.
In case `myArray` is `{2,2,3,5,0,0,0,0}` this will print out:

```
2*2*3*5*0*0*0*0*
```

You have to take into account the checking for the last element of the array if you don't want to print `*` after the last element.